# reinstall wireless driver

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers

My network center is not displaying any wireless connections even though I know there are several in the area.

I am trying to reinstall my wireless driver with the hopes that I can get it working. In an effort to find my wireless card I ran the fallowing command with the results below: `sudo lshw -c network`.

```
sudo lshw -c network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82566MM Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 03
       serial: 00:1b:38:7f:df:be
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k duplex=full firmware=0.3-0 ip=10.0.0.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:44 memory:d8500000-d851ffff memory:d8520000-d8520fff ioport:5000(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: PRO/Wireless 4965 AG or AGN [Kedron] Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:10:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 61
       serial: 00:13:e8:b9:d8:e7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwl4965 driverversion=3.13.0-32-generic firmware=228.61.2.24 ip=10.0.0.4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:47 memory:d8000000-d8001fff
```

Comment: Any result using `iwlist scan`? This is not windows, so "uninstalling driver" is not the first option.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: rfkill list all and also: dmesg | grep iwl Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that [this - Intel® Wireless WiFi Link 4965AGN](http://www.intel.com/products/wireless/wireless_n/overview.htm) - is your WiFi card based off `product: PRO/Wireless 4965 AG or AGN [Kedron] Network Connection` & `vendor: Intel Corporation` as listed in your question.

You should be able to download your drivers for that device from [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&FamilyId=1783&ProductID=2753&ProdId=2753).

Comment: I went to the link and selected the linux version but it said that the page was unavailable. How do I uninstall the existing driver?

Comment: @Mike That's strange. I was having a similar issue with random pages being missing - must be something on Intel's end. As for removing the driver, run `dpkg -s | grep intel` and post the results. If it's too long, create an Ubuntu Paste at paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: dpkg -s | grep intel
dpkg-query: error: --status needs at least one package name argument

Use --help for help about querying packages.

Comment: @Mike *facepalm*. Sorry, I meant to say run `dpkg -l | grep intel`. My bad, I'm sorry :P

Comment: lol that's ok. 

dpkg -l | grep intel
ii  intel-gpu-tools                                       1.3-0ubuntu2.1                                      amd64        tools for debugging the Intel graphics driver
ii  libdrm-intel1:amd64                                   2.4.52-1                                            amd64        Userspace interface to intel-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel                              2:2.99.910-0ubuntu1.3                               amd64        X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver

Comment: @Mike Actually, if you *could* do an Ubuntu paste, that would make it a bit easier to read... nbd if you don't want to :) AFAICS you don't have any Intel drivers installed, so you shouldn't have to remove anything. Just as confirmation, the Intel WiFi Link 4965AGN *is* your card, correct?

Comment: How do I do ubuntu paste?

Comment: @Mike Go to http://paste.ubuntu.com and copy/paste :D It's really handy some times :) We need to get you to 20 rep so this can be taken care of in chat.

Comment: @Mike Try installing `linux-modules-backports` via `sudo apt-get install linux-modules-backports`. That was supposedly something that resolved a user's issue [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1301897).

Comment: @Mike Actually, before you install that package (unless you already have) go ahead and try following the instructions given [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1357099). This is the exact same card as yours and the exact same issue as well.

Comment: I guess I don't have enough reputation to chat. lol I ran the command and it said E: Unable to locate package linux-modules-backports

Comment: @Mike Yeah, it's kinda annoying some times, but a necessary counter-measure on a site like this. Otherwise, chat would be overrun with bots and spammers :P. Go ahead and look at the bug I linked and try the solution given there and report back, okay?

Comment: I ran the first command and came up with this. I tried to use the ubuntu paste so I am hoping it will work the way I used it. modprobe -nv pci:v0000808d00004229sv00008086sd00001100bc02sc80i00
modprobe: FATAL: Module pci:v0000808d00004229sv00008086sd00001100bc02sc80i00 not found.

Comment: @Mike Sorry I didn't respond earlier, I had to sleep. Such a pain that. Go ahead and run this: `grep iwl4965 /etc/modprobe.d/*`. As for how you use Ubuntu Pastebin, go to the website, paste the result of the command in the **Contents** box, put your name (Mike) in the **Poster** box, and click **Paste!**. You should get a link and then you should be given a link. Post that here.

Comment: I did the command and it just sent me down a line and it was blank. http://paste.ubuntu.com/9626760/

Comment: I just disconnected the ethernet and my wifi is working miraculously. I'm not sure what did the trick but something we did must have worked. Thanks for your input. I actually went to bed soon after I posted the response last night so it's totally ok that you hadn't responded that night. :-)

Comment: @Mike Sweet! Just to check, have you rebooted since it has been working? That's usually the final check. If the WiFi survives the  reboot, hooray! As for the lack of output for the `modprobe`, I believe that's normal, and if the WiFi started working *after* that command, then there's the solution!

Comment: After reading your comment I rebooted and it does still work.

Comment: I think I did it right. Let me know if it didn't put your answer as the answer to the question.

Comment: @Mike Nope, you did just fine! Glad that my solution worked out! :D And, I just realized I forgot to welcome you to Ask Ubuntu! Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

Answer (score 1):

Intel has a generic driver that covers the 82566MM Gigabit Network.  It comes under the e1000 series, and you can download that from [here](https://copy.com/qmsN2RYOlyWkpStg).

As far as the PRO/Wireless 4965 AG or AGN [Kedron] Network, you can download the driver from [Linux wireless](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlegacy).

Comment: I downloaded the file and clicked on it but I am not sure what to do beyond that.

Comment: I just disconnected from the ethernet connection and I have wifi again. Maybe just downloading the package fixed it without executing any files? Thanks for the help! :-)